# akamai not load my image and change link page then not load my image, trying custom loader and akamai loader but not workink

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

next.config.js

```
images: {
    loader: "akamai",
    path: "./components/hero.js",
  },
```

hero.js

```
import Image from "next/image";

const Hero = () => {
  const myImageLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
    return `http://localhost:3000${src}?imwidth=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
  };
  return (
    <>
<div class="hidden duration-700 ease-in-out" data-carousel-item>
            <Image
              loader={myImageLoader}
              src="/../public/sliders/slide-naqas.png"
              class="absolute block max-w-full h-auto -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2"
              width="1350"
              height="617"
              alt="Hero Illustration"
              quality={75}
            />
          </div>
</>
```

akamai not load my image and change link page then not load my image,  trying custom loader and akamai loader but not workink